# applet object give nullpointer exception when first time calling method on object with java update 1.7

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I update my jre from 1.6 update 31 to 1.7 update05, now when first time applet object is created and java script call the method on applet object then it give null pointer exception but and after that it does not occur but when I put an alert just before the call to method on object then at alert object is shown and this exception does not occur. Can any body tell me what is the problem and what should I do to resolve it.

```
    <% response.write "<OBJECT "%>
    classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11m1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
    WIDTH=<%= iWidth  %> HEIGHT=<%= iHeight %>   
    hspace=0 vspace=0 border=0 align=top NAME="graph"  
    <% 'codebase="res/plugins/j2re-1_4_0_01-windows-i586-i.exe#Version=1,4,0,1"  %>
    type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4"  
    id=JavaBeansBridge_Object1>
    <param name ="CODE"             value="com.graph.Graph.class" >
  <param name ="CODEBASE"           value="res/applet/" >
  <param name ="ARCHIVE"            value="graph.jar">
  <param name="Type" id="Param1" value="<%=Type%>">         
  <param name="NodeName" value="<%= NodeName %>">           
  <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4">
 <param name="scriptable"   value="true">
 </OBJECT>
```

and the javascript code to call applet method is as below

```
<pre>
//alert (document.graph);
document.graph.setType(inputType);
</pre>
```

If i uncomment alert then null then exception does not occur.

Comment: Not without code. The only problem with Java 7 that I had so far was relying on the (undocumented) feature that declared methods were returned in declaration order in Java 6 whereas in Java 7 this is no more the case (using reflection API).

Comment: NullpointerException is not a html error... show the applet problem code

Comment: above is the code for java applet, and I think the issue is the function in which setType method is called on graph object, is called at body onload of the page, so I think this called before the Object Creation, and If I apply the alert before this calling then till the time I click on OK button of alert the graph object of applet instansiat ,that's why null pointer exception does not occur and also once object has instantiate again this exception does not occur. So could you please tell me how I should call the java script function after object instansiation.